# Why Is This Modal-Backdrop Rendering But Not The Modal-Dialogue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, bootstrap-modal

thanks for reading. I love you all.

I have a JavaScript function which should load a modal dialogue with AJAX and display it over the page I am on. It is working on some levels - the AJAX html is being received and loaded into the page, the modal backdrop is popping up when the button that should launch the dialogue is pressed. The dialogue itself is not rendering though. I am fairly new to JavaScript and this project has definitely taught me a lot, but if you all have some advise and suggestions I would really appreciate it.

Here is the JavaScript portion - which should load into the top div.

```
<div id="loadModal">
</div>

@Html.Partial("_InspectionSubNav", "InspectionSub")
<div id="contents">
<h2>Inspections</h2>
@if (Authorizer.Authorize(Enertrek.Inspections.Permissions.AssignInspection))
{
<div class="box_rounded">
    @Html.Partial("_TableLoader", "AssignInspectionTable")
</div>
}
```

```
<script>
function myFunc(x) {
    var thisurl = '@HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Url.Action("GetAssignInspectorModal", "Inspection", new {area = "Enertrek.Inspections" }))' + '/' + x;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.p3table-loader').on("click", '.singleAction a', function () {
            //helper.Action("GetAssignInspectorModal", "Inspection", new { id = entity.Id, area = "Enertrek.Inspections" });
            $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: thisurl,
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#loadModal').html(data);
                    $('#loadModal').modal({
                        toggle: false,
                        show: true
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
}




 </script>
```

I also can pull HTML from the inspector if people think that will help - right now there is a lot of it and it will make this post significantly longer.

Comment: the solution is this

$('#loadModal ,modal').modal({...})